# Glasslab Cluster Library

Tags: python

I want to install a library called Glasslab-Cluster Library ([Glasslab Cluster](http://glasslab.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/u/fhs/gclust/doc/intro.html#download-and-install)) for python. But I found that it just provided Linux and Ubuntu install commands.

Are there any ways that I can install this library on windows?

Thank you and please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the link you provided, there is a "setup.py" file in the source package.

So, download the sources, unzip them in a separate folder, go to that folder and type

```
python setup.py install
```

You will probably need the MinGW GCC compiler (free) to make this run.

Hope this helps !  (I have no windows systems anymore and can not test this)